# Run command in client cmd with php

Tags: php

How can I run this exec on client side :

```
exec("shutdown \r");
```

For example when the client opens this file (the file with above function) in internet, that shutdown command run in that client cmd system and the client system go for shutdown.

What should i do?
**how about javascript ? is there any way in java to do this ?**

Comment: You can't, PHP is a server side language and not client side. When they open your page it will execute that command on your server and only if you have the right access to execute it.

Comment: Do you want to hack the user? It is impossible to shutdown the user's computer through its browser...

Comment: how about javascript ? is there any way in java to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done
PHP is a server side